# How to demo examples of embeded systems?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, robotics, demo, rfid

It seems that a lot of small business people have a need for some customized embedded systems, but don't really know too much about the possibilities and cannot quite envisage them.

I had the same problem when trying to explain what Android could do; I was generally met with glazed eyes - and then I made a few demos. Somehow, being able to see something - to be able to touch it and play around with it – people have that cartoon lightbulb moment.

Even if it is not directly applicable to them, a demo starts them thinking about what could be useful to them.

The sort of person I am talking about may or may not be technical, but is certainly intelligent, having built from scratch a business which turns over millions.

Their needs are varied, from RFID or GPS asset & people tracking, to simple stock control systems,  displays, communications, sometime satellite, sometimes VPN or LAN (wifi or RJ45). A lot of it needs a good back-end database with a web-site to display, query, data-mine …

So, to get to the question, I am looking for a simple project, or projects, which will cause that cartoon lightbulb moment. It need not be too complicated as those who need complicated solutions are generally tech-savvy, just something straightforward & showing what could be done to streamline their business and make it more profitable.

It would be nice it if could include some wifi/RJ45 comms, communicate across the internet (e.g not just a micro-controller attached to a single PC – that should then communicate with a server/web-site), an RFID reader would be nice, something actually happening (LEDs, sounds, etc), plus some database, database analysis/data-ming – something end-to-end, preferably in both directions.

A friend was suggesting a Rube Goldberg like contraption with a Lego Mindstorms attached to a local PC, but also  controllable from a remote PC (representing head office) or web site. That would show remote control of devices. Maybe it could pick up some RFID tags and move them around (at random, or on command), representing stock control (or maybe employee/asset movement within a factory or warehouse (Location Based Services/GIS)), which cold then be shown on the web site, with some nice charts & graphs etc.

Any other ideas?

How best to implement it? One of those micro-controller starter kites like http://www.nerdkits.com/  ? Maybe some Lego, or similar robot kit, a few cheap RFID readers … anything else?

And – the $409,600 question – what's a good, representative demo which demonstrate as many functionalities as possible, as impressively as possible, with the least effort? (keeping it modular and allowing for easy addition of features, since there is such a wide area to cover)

p.s a tie with an Adroid slate PC would be welcome too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your customers might respond better to a solid looking R/C truck which seeks RFID tags than to a Lego robot.  Lego is cool, but it has a bit of a slapped-together 'kiddie' feel.

What if you:

- scatter some RFID tags across the conference room.
- add a GPS & wifi transmitter to your truck.
- drive the truck to the tag

  - (manually - unless you want to invest a lot of time in steering algorithms).
- have a PC drawing a real-time track of the trucks path.
- every the truck gets within range of the tag, add it to an inventory list on the screen, showing item id, location, time recorded, total units so far.

  - indicate the position of the item on the map.

I'd be impressed.

Is it 'least effort'?  I don't know, but I'd hope that if this is the type of solution you are pitching, that you already have a good handle on how to read GPS and RFID devices, how to establish a TCP or UDP connection with wifi, how to send and decode packets.  Add some simple graphics and database lookup, and you are set.

Regarding hardware, I don't have any first hand experience with any of these, but the [GadgetPC Wi-Fi G Kit](http://microcontrollershop.com/product_info.php?products_id=3535) + a [USB RFID reader](http://www.trossenrobotics.com/p/REDBEE-Wireless-rfid-reader.aspx) + a USB GPS reciever looks like a nice platform for experimenting with this.

Comment: +1 Thanks for a very well thought-out suggestion. I will definitely be considering this. I will go now & check those kits which you suggest.

Comment: Sounds good, if the GPS works indoors. I wouldn't depend on that.

Comment: @Craig, That did occur to me after I wrote this up.  Maybe an accelerometer instead - sample quickly and integrate position.  You only need to convey the idea of the value of real-time position tracking - I don't think the track needs to be super-accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Many chip manufactures have off-the-shelf demo boards. [Microchip](http://www.microchipdirect.com/) has some great demo boards for TCP/IP communications on an embedded system. I haven't seen one yet for RFID. Showing potential customers some of these demos could get them thinking about what is possible.

Comment: +1 thanks. Ok, I will look at Microchip.  RFID is no problem as the reader will communicate via serial port or USB.